# Creating multiple clients for topics

Tags: python, mqtt, subscribe

from a Sqlite3 database I am collecting multiple mqtt topics that I want to subscribe. I pick the topics out of the database and put them into a list. 
Now I want to create a client for each topic (each Item in the list) and subscribe to that topic. So that I have multiple clients which are subcribing different topics.

This is how I get the Topics out of the Database:

```py
connection = sqlite3.connect(MainDatabaseDirectory)
cursor = connection.cursor() 
cursor.execute("""SELECT * FROM 'List'""")
for dataset in cursor:
    topic = ''.join(dataset[0])
    topicList.append(topic)
```

And this is how i tried to create multiple clients and to subscribe to the topics:

```py
   for i in range(len(topicList)):
       topic = ''.join(topicList[i])
       client = mqtt.Client(topic)
       client.connect(mqttBrokerIpAddress, Port)
       client.subscribe(topic)
```

Can anyone tell me, where my Problem is or what I need to do better? 
Is it even possible to create multiple clients to subscribe different topics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, First you really don't want to be creating multiple clients within the same process without a really really good reason (about the only one I can think of is a backend server acting on behalf of multiple users that have different ACLs).

A single client can subscribe to many topics (as we discussed in the answer when you [posted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57204569/504554) this first time round).

The code you have posted is creating multiple clients, but then immediately throwing away any reference to them and overwriting it with the next client it creates.

Create 1 client, subscribe to many topics.

```
def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc)
  global topicList
  for i in range(len(topicList)):
       topic = ''.join(topicList[i])
       client.subscribe(topic)

def on_message(client, userdata, message)
  # do something with the message
  # the topic the message arrived on will be in
  # message.topic

connection = sqlite3.connect(MainDatabaseDirectory)
cursor = connection.cursor() 
cursor.execute("""SELECT * FROM 'List'""")
for dataset in cursor:
    topic = ''.join(dataset[0])
    topicList.append(topic) 

client = mqtt.Client()
client.on_connect = on_connect
client.on_message = on_message
client.connect(mqttBrokerIpAddress, Port)
client.loop_forever()
```

Comment: Okay...I am going to try this...But where is the subscription in your code?

Comment: in the `on_connect` callback

Comment: oh I'm sorry! Haven't seen it! Thank you so much! It's working!